# Failing POST requests to Magnolia CMS Website 403 error

Tags: magnolia

we have encountered a problem with Magnolia CMS 6.2 on the customer's website.

All POST requests to this website come with a 403 error.
All required settings for the 'anonymous' are set up.
Magnolia Version 6.2.37
Application server: Tomcat 9.0.58

Could you please tell us how the problem can be solved?

Best regards
Alex